# jQuery Ajax request inside Ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, git

### EDIT: It's telling me that my li is an illegal token. Still not sure what to do about this as I thought I was appending inside a ul

So I have to fetch a JSON array of some public Github repos and append the title, link, description, and basic information from the first 10 commits of each repo to the page. I already have the title, link and description working, but I'm lost when it comes to bringing in the commits. They're located at a different address than the initial information, so I made a second ajax request inside my first one to the commits address, but nothing is working. It may just be a syntax error or something as I've found from extensive searching that it is possible to nest ajax requests.

Here's my code, chopped up into each separate function (I've replaced the org name with 'name' for anonymity's sake):

main function:

```
function main() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/name/repos',
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    complete: function(data){
      display_content(data);
    }
  });
}
main();
```

content display function:

```
function display_content(_data){
  for (var i = 0; i < _data.responseJSON.length; i++) {
    $("#listing").append(
      "<h2>" +
        "<a href=\"" + _data.responseJSON[i].html_url + "\">" + _data.responseJSON[i].full_name + "</a></h2>" +
      "<p>" + _data.responseJSON[i].description +
        "<h3>Latest Commits</h3>" + 
        "<ul id= \"" + _data.responseJSON[i].name + "commits\">"
    );

    commits(_data.responseJSON[i].name);

    $('#listing').append(
        "</ul>" +
      "</p>" +
      "<br/>"
    );
  }
}
```

commit information function:

```
function commits(repo){
  $('#listing').find('h3').text("Latest Commits to user/" + repo);
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/user/' + repo + '/commits',
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    complete: function(commit_data){
      for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $('#listing').append(
          "<li>
            <div>
              <img src=\"" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.avatar_url + "\"> 
              <a href=\"https://github.com/" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.login + "\">
                <b>" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.login + "</b>
              </a>
              <b>" + ($.timeago(commit_data.responseJSON[i].commit.committer.date)) + "</b><br />
              <i>SHA: " + commit_data.responseJSON[i].sha + "</i>
            </div>
            <a href=\"https://github.com/user/" + repo + "/commit/" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].sha + 
              "\" target=\"_blank\">" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].commit.message +
            "</a>
          </li>"
        );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, I apologize in advance. I know the problem lies somewhere in the last two functions but I wanted to include everything to be sure.
If anyone has any experience with grabbing and parsing Git repo info I would really appreciate any advice on this. I'm willing to scrap everything and start over if need be to make this work, but I would like to avoid using any libraries aside from jQuery.

Thank you to anyone who helps! I appreciate it.

Comment: When you say 'nothing is working', 2nd ajax never gets called, or 2nd ajax never finishes, or 2nd ajax gives error, or ?

Comment: put alert on "Complete". is it working?

Comment: It's really hard to tell. When I run my index.html file, all that shows up on the page is a header that I manually typed into the html, which is all that I have in the html aside from the div with id=listing.
Also none of my errors are alerting and if I place alerts elsewhere they don't show... I do know that if I cut out the call to the commits() function in display_content(), everything aside from the commit info will show correctly.

Comment: https://api.github.com/orgs/name/repos is assuming an organization with name `name`. And there is no organization with name `name`. So, your first `$.ajax` is getting a `Not Found` error.

Comment: use your firbug console to findout the errors

Comment: @dreyescat I took out the org name for anonymity, I mentioned it above. I know that's not a problem.
Also thank you NaveenChandraTiwari that helps a lot actually, I didn't think of that at all.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't read the post well ;). I see that you are not properly closing the strings in your `$('#listing').append(` call in your `commits` function. You have to close the string when you split a string in multiple lines or use the `\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's telling me that my li is an illegal token. Still not sure what to do about this as I thought I was appending inside a ul

You are using multi-line string literal for adding html.  The line breaks need to be escaped, and this can be done via a backslash.

Change to

```
function commits(repo){
  $('#listing').find('h3').text("Latest Commits to user/" + repo);
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/user/' + repo + '/commits',
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    complete: function(commit_data){
      for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $('#listing').append(
          "<li>"+
            "<div>"+
              "<img src=\"" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.avatar_url + "\">"+
              "<a href=\"https://github.com/" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.login + "\">"+
                "<b>" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].author.login + "</b>"+
              "</a>"+
              "<b>" + ($.timeago(commit_data.responseJSON[i].commit.committer.date)) + "</b><br />"+
              "<i>SHA: " + commit_data.responseJSON[i].sha + "</i>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<a href=\"https://github.com/user/" + repo + "/commit/" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].sha + 
              "\" target=\"_blank\">" + commit_data.responseJSON[i].commit.message +
            "</a>"+
          "</li>"
        );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Just went to bed so I'll try this first thing in the morning. Though I'm sure you're right, why would the append in my display_content function work without the escapes where the append in the commits function doesn't?

Comment: @homeofmatt The html in `display_content` is not multi-line, ie, you are terminating and merging the strings (`"</ul>" + "</p>" + "<br/>").  You can try a similar thing here or use `\` to escape the end of line.

Comment: Having thought about this a bit further, it might be better to use quotes/plus instead.  It makes it easier to read.  Will update the answer.